# Customize quick launch menu and site action menu in My Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, customization

I've been asked to customize the following:

1. In the left quick launch menu, is it possible to remove these menus: Documents, Lists, discussions and Sites? These menus need to be remove/disable/hidden by default when the user creates it's My Site.
2. In the site action menu, is it possible to remove/disable/hide the Create menu, so the user can't create any kind of subsite, lists, etc..?

I'm working with MOSS 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using MOSS 2007, you can customise the menu on the left by going to Site Actions -> Site Settings and Navigation in the middle.

[Sharepoint Navigation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558975.aspx)

Create rights are based on the roles assigned to the user logged in, so not giving the user create rights should remove this from the menus.